# What's wrong with my php.ini?

Tags: php

i'd like to know whats wring with my php.ini because I cant attach any file more than 200kb. I've already modified the `upload_max_filesize` and my `post_max_size` but still nothing happens. I'm using xampp, localhost and php `mail()` function. Every comment will be much very appreciated. thank you

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize

upload_max_filesize = 20M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20


; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 40M
```

Comment: are you sure you edited right file? Have you restarted your server?

Comment: Have you restarted apache after making the ini file changes?

Comment: Are you positive you have permission to edit your `php.ini` file? Are you on shared hosting?

Comment: Thank you all for giving your comments. I've already restarted my apache after making changes and yes I do have permission to edit the php.ini file. But still I cant manage to send more than 200kb file to my email

Comment: Please check your web server error log. There is possibility, you have reached maximum request size - for example with Apache MaxRequestLen/FcgidMaxRequestLen Directive

Answer (score -1):

Many time upload_max_filesize didn't work on windows (xampp and wamp) . I recommend to switch to LAMP Or if you have to upload database you can use MYSQL workbench on windows system .

Comment: Actually I'm just creating a report page where they can send their info's and be able to attach some files.